# C++ concepts restriction

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

I am in the process of trying out C++20 concepts as a way to achieve static polymorphism without CRTPs.

There is something I don't quite understand though. Concepts allow me to specify the *minimum* functionality that a template parameter should support, but they do not seem to place an upper bound on the functionality.

Say I'm writing some concept `is_something` along with a function `func` that requires some template parameter to respect `is_something`. With regular static polymorphism, I can be sure that I don't accidentally use *more than what `is_something` provides*. With concepts however, I can inadvertantly use *more* than what the concept guarantees, and I won't ever know it until I instantiate the function with a different type conforming to `is_something` but lacking said functionality.

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept is_something = requires(const T& s) {
  { s.bar() };
};

struct MySomething {
  void bar() const {
    std::cout << "bar()" << std::endl;
  }
  
  void bar2() const {
    std::cout << "bar2()" << std::endl;
  }
};



template <is_something F>
void func(const F& s) {
  s.bar();
  s.bar2(); // <- oops, inadvertantly used stuff from MySomething not covered by is_something
}
```

That seems very annoying as a library provider, because I have no way to make sure the concepts I provide are indeed covering all the use cases, and users of the library could very well have `is_something`-compliant classes that won't work in practice.

Did I miss something obvious, or are concepts in fact a poor choice for static interfaces?

Comment: Something wrong with CRTP?

Comment: @paulsanders nothing wrong per se, though CRTP makes the code convoluted and overall hard to follow. I expected concepts to be a more readable way to express the same thing

Comment: Concepts are not perfect, but there's no better replacement either. The original proposal was very substantial; many corners were cut and left us with the **concepts lite**  being shipped in C++20. CRTP is not a replacement either: it doesn't restrict the type. The least concepts can do is retire SFINAE adhoc tricks, and provide shorter cleaner alternatives for irreadable `enable_if` tricks.

Comment: Rust restricts the calls... C++ does not restrict the call... I don't know if there exist a static analyzer to check that in C++...

Comment: What do you mean by “With regular static polymorphism, I can be sure that I don't accidentally use _more than what `is_something` provides_.”?  All static polymorphism is checked, per-type, only on usage.